# IndexOutOfBounds, when it should not

Tags: java

I am learning the Java language, and I am trying to make the MasterMind game.
I get the following error while trying to compile, and after trying to debug the code, I cant find the mistake:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 97, Size: 4
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:474)
    at mastermind.Combinacion.aciertos(Combinacion.java:115)
    at mastermind.Combinacion.principal(Combinacion.java:36)
    at mastermind.MasterMind.main(MasterMind.java:21)
Java Result: 1
```

The following code is the method "aciertos", that given a secret key, and a combination, tells you how many of your letters are in the secret key.

```
    public int aciertos(Combinacion comb){
    int aciert = 0;
    List<Character> clave = new ArrayList();
    // Transform the key to a List, so we can easily check what contains and remove elements
    for(char c : this.codigo){
        clave.add(c);
    }
    // We go though the user try, and we check if the letter it is in the secret key list. If it is, we remove it from the list, to avoid counting twice if the user has a letter repeated and it is only once in the secret key.
    for (int i = 0; i < comb.codigo.length; i++) {
        if(clave.contains(comb.codigo[i])){
            aciert++;
            clave.remove(comb.codigo[i]);
        }
    }
    return aciert;
}
```

These are the fields from the Combinacion class:

```
//Size of each combination
private int tamano = 4;
//Los valores válidos son: blanco, negro, azul, rojo, verde, marron
private static Character[] valoresValidos = {'b', 'n', 'a', 'r', 'v', 'm'};
private static List<Character> valores = Arrays.asList(valoresValidos);
private char[] codigo = new char[tamano];
```

P.D: I should start writing and commenting everything in English, sorry for the spanish words.

Comment: What is line 115 of `Combinacion.java`

Comment: What is the type of `codigo`?  `char[]`?

Comment: You have two fields called `tamano` in the `Combinacion` class?

Comment: @balwinder-singh clave.remove(comb.codigo[i]);

Comment: @Raul You already have the answer. Try it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `char` argument to `clave.remove(com.codigo[i])` is being promoted to an `int` instead of being boxed to a `Character`.  This ends up calling `ArrayList#remove(int index)` rather than the method that you want (`ArrayList#remove(Object o)`).

Try manually boxing the `char` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < comb.codigo.length; i++) {
    if(clave.contains(comb.codigo[i])){
        aciert++;
        clave.remove(Character.valueOf(comb.codigo[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand why the index was 97!. Actually, it was the value of the char ('a' in this case). That solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The error says on its first line that you're trying to read index 97 in an ArrayList that has just 4 elements. `ArrayList.remove()` uses an index as a parameter, not the object to remove:

```
clave.remove(comb.codigo[i])
```

has to be replaced by:

```
clave.remove(clave.indexOf(comb.codigo[i]))
```

Comment: But, wouldnt remove the element of the list in the same position as the array? I want to remove from the list the first element at i position in the array.

Comment: That's what my code is doing. indexOf returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

Comment: You are right, I didnt get it at first sight. Both answers are nice, I accepted the other it was easier for me to understand, but I would like to accept yours as well.

Comment: Thanks @Raul, no problem

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the clave.remove() line is using the contents of comb.codigo[i] as an index. The value being used in this case is 97, which corresponds to a lowercase 'a'. Is that what the array contains?